# Design Approach for multiple apps from same codebase (Android)

Tags: android

For android app, What is the best approach to design an app that can support multiple clients. Each client having their own set of images and texts. The images are with the same set of filename.

Instead of replacing the images and strings.xml each time when build, is there other better approach?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. "can support multiple clients. Each client having their own set of images and texts." is not really straight forward.

Comment: What Development Environment are you using? Eclipse? Just replacing strings.xml and the images in drawable directory seems to be the best case you can achieve. In Eclipse you might need to setup a project for each client and share the source (not sure if that really works)